# Selecting same column value using multiple variables

Tags: sql

I have a table `tags`. Two columns `tag_name`, `value`.

I want to select `value` based on `tag_name`. Eg. if `tag_name` is "type" I want to select `value` as "type_value" and if `tag_name` is "material" I want to select it as "material_value". I tried using the following case statement but got syntax error:

```
select
case tag_name
when 'type'
then value as type_value
when 'material'
then value as material_value
end
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Sample data in tags table:

```
  id            tag_name                   value                 taggable_id
1671223  collection          Chunky                         1060528713
1671224  type                Chains                         1060528713
1671225  occasion            Special Occasions or Gifts     1060528713
1671226  material            Alloy                          1060528713
1671227  gemstones           Pearl                          1060528713
1671228  home_page_link      Statement_Necklaces            1060528713
1671217  collection      Traditional and Imitation      1060528712
1671218  type            Bangles                        1060528712
1671219  occasion        Special Occasions or Gifts     1060528712
1671220  material        Alloy                          1060528712
1671221  plating         Yellow Gold Plating            1060528712
1671222  gemstones       Cubic Zirconia                 1060528712
```

I am iterating over the table and want to store values based on `tag_name`

So I want something like

```
taggable_id    collection_value            type_value   occasion_value               material_value      plating_value       gemstones_value
1060528712   Traditional and Imitation       Bangles     Special Occasions or Gifts      Alloy        Yellow Gold Plating    Cubic Zrconia             
1060528713   Chunky                          Chains      Special Occasions or Gifts      Alloy                               Pearl
```

Comment: If you need dynamic column names you have to build your query dynamically. There is no "normal" SQL statement to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to have the query to be dynamic and if you can live with hard coded values in the query I believe this should work:

```
select 
    taggable_id, 
    max(collection_value) as collection_value,
    max(type_value) as type_value,
    max(occasion_value) as occasion_value,
    max(material_value) as material_value,
    max(plating_value) as plating_value,
    max(gemstones_value) as gemstone_value
from (
    select 
        taggable_id,
        case tag_name when 'collection' then value end as collection_value,
        case tag_name when 'type' then value end as type_value,
        case tag_name when 'occasion' then value end as occasion_value,
        case tag_name when 'material' then value end as material_value,
        case tag_name when 'plating' then value end as plating_value,
        case tag_name when 'gemstones' then value end as gemstones_value
    from tags 
) subquery 
group by taggable_id
order by taggable_id
```

If you need all tags to become columns another option would be to use a dynamic pivot query:

```
DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Column AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Column= ISNULL(@Column + ',','') + QUOTENAME(tag_name)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tag_name FROM tags) AS Tags

SET @Query =
  N'SELECT taggable_id, ' + @Column + '
    FROM (SELECT taggable_id, value, tag_name FROM tags) tb
    PIVOT(MAX(value)
          FOR tag_name IN (' + @Column + ')) AS PivotTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

It won't produce the exact output you asked for though as ordering and column labels will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    WITH Pivoted
    AS
    (
        select taggable_id,collection ,type,occasion,material,plating,gemstones 
        from tags 
        pivot
        (
          max(value)
          for tag_name in (collection,type,occasion,material,plating,gemstones)
        ) piv
    ) 
    SELECT 
       taggable_id,
       MAX(collection) AS collection_Value,
       MAX(type) AS type_Value,
       MAX(occasion) AS occasion_Value,
       MAX(material) AS material_Value,
       MAX(plating) AS plating_Value,
       MAX(gemstones) AS gemstones_Value
    FROM Pivoted
    GROUP BY taggable_id;
```

Comment: This won't produce the desired result as you're missing taggable_id in the two select statements. If you add that attribute, the query will give the correct results though.